# Get all items that match a DropLink option in Sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore

This seems like it should be easy. Maybe it is and I'm just overthinking it. I have a bunch of items that have a category field set via a DropLink. I want to grab all of the items that match one of those options. E.g., Grab a list of all items where Category=Brochure. I can't seem to get the ID of the Droplink option to match against the Category option on the Item itself.

EDIT: Included current code by request.

```
public List<PoolDownload> Manuals
        {
            get
            {
                LookupField cat = (LookupField)this.Item.Fields["Category"];
                return this.Downloads.Where(i => (i.Item.TemplateID == PoolDownload.TemplateId) &&
                                        (i.Item.GlassCast<Pdp.Pool.Website.Business.Entities.PoolDownload>().Category.ToString() == cat.TargetID.ToString()))
                                        .ToList();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post your code to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: What is the type of the Category property?

Comment: @Barbosa The Category field is a DropLink field.

Comment: What's the C# class type for the Category property?

Comment: @Barbosa It's a Guid

Comment: I think it's because you're comparing a Guid.ToString() to a Sitecore.Data.ID.ToString().  I'm testing this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is you're comparing a `Guid.ToString()` to a `Sitecore.Data.ID.ToString()`. These two statements return different values:

```
var guidToString = Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.Guid.ToString();
// "2a6a1d9a-be1d-411b-821a-7e63775280b3"

var idToString = Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.ToString();
// "{2A6A1D9A-BE1D-411B-821A-7E63775280B3}"
```

Cast the `TargetID` to a `Guid` as well and you should be good.

And to answer your question in your comment below about displaying the "Download Items" grouped by Category, you could use the GroupBy method, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx like this:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<Guid, PoolDownload>> Manuals
{
    get
    {
        LookupField cat = (LookupField)this.Item.Fields["Category"];

        return this.Downloads.Where(i =>
            i.Item.TemplateID == PoolDownload.TemplateId
            && i.Item.GlassCast<Pdp.Pool.Website.Business.Entities.PoolDownload>().Category.ToString() == cat.TargetID.Guid.ToString())
            .GroupBy(i => i.Category);
    }
}
```

And then, to loop over the results in the new Manuals property, you could do something like this:

```
foreach(var categoryGroup in Manuals)
{
    var categoryGuid = categoryGroup.Key;

    foreach(var download in categoryGroup)
    {
        var downloadInCurrentGroup = download.Item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Barbosa! That helps me match the ID's. Any idea how to grab the ID of the option I'm testing against?

Comment: No problem.

Where are you setting the option that you're testing against?  Is it hard-coded in your code?  Is it a field on the page item?  Is it a field on the datasource item?  How does the Content Author select a Category to begin with?

Comment: I have "download items" which have a droplink field which the content author uses to set the Category. These are the options I want to test against (Manual, Brochure, etc...). Download Items are then associated with Product Items via a Downloads field on the Product template. A product can have multiple Download Items associated with it. What I'm trying to ultimately do is display all of the Download Items for a Product, grouped by their Category.

Comment: I just updated my answer to provide suggestions on how you could use the GroupBy method to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: I will give that a try today. Thanks so much for the help! As you can probably tell I'm not really a .NET expert so I really appreciate your taking the time to assist.